# How to display Only 5 items in div listbox at any time while scrolling by pressing up and down buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I have a div list box that is populated from an array. Currently the list box shows all 10 items and i can scroll down and up by pressing buttons.

I wonder how i can limit the list box to show only 5 items at any time.For example at start it should show items from test1 till test5 and when my selector reaches item 5(by pressing down button) after that selector should stays at bottom of list box and keep showing item 6 onward  and removing test1...

I would appreciate if you guys help me achieve this task.Thanks

(Note:if i press up button instead of down button it should also show 5 items at any time but this time instead of removing items from start of list box it should keep adding)

This is how now shows the data now:

[image]

but i want to present data like this when selector reaches test6:

[image]

```
<script>

    var nameList =  ["test1", "test2", "test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"];

    function PopulateMyDivList()
    {  
        var listHTML = "";        
        var i=0;
        var container = document.getElementById("MyDivList");    
        for (var name in nameList)
        {
            listHTML = nameList[name] ;                   
            container.innerHTML += '<div id="item'+i+'">'+listHTML+'</div>';    
            i++;
        }    
        item0.style.backgroundImage= "url(./selector.png)";    
    }

    var counterUp=0;

    function Navi(a)
    {    
        if (a =="Up")
        {
            document.getElementById('item'+counterUp).style.backgroundImage= "url(none)";    
            counterUp=counterUp-1;    
            document.getElementById('item'+counterUp).style.backgroundImage= "url(./selector.png)";    
        }
        else if (a =="Down")
        {    
            document.getElementById('item'+counterUp).style.backgroundImage= "url(none)";
            counterUp++;
            document.getElementById('item'+counterUp).style.backgroundImage= "url(./selector.png)";    
        }
        else
        {
        }    
    }

    window.onload = function () {  
        PopulateMyDivList();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <button type=button onClick=Navi('Up');>Up </button><br>
    <button type=button onClick=Navi('Down');>Down </button><br>    

    <div id="MyDivList" class="style_MyDivList">     
    <div id="Total">10</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add/remove some items to do so.

Here is a demo fully commented.
I replaced the background image with just a background color.

```js
var nameList =  ["test1", "test2", "test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"];

var container = $("#MyDivList");
var maxItems = 5;
var nameList_last = nameList.length-1;
var counterUp = 0;


function Navi(a){
  
  if (a =="Up"){
    if(counterUp==0){
      return;
    }
    
    // Decrease counterUp.
    counterUp--;
    
    // If counterUp is zero or more, add the new item on top.
    if((counterUp)>=0){
    $('<div id="item'+counterUp+'">'+nameList[counterUp]+'</div>').insertBefore($("[id^='item']").first());
    }

    // If there is now more item than the maximum, remove the last.
    if($("[id^='item']").length>maxItems){
      $("[id^='item']").last().remove();
    }
    
  }else{
    if(counterUp==nameList_last){
      return;
    }
    
    // Remove the item on top of the list.
    $('#item'+counterUp).remove();
    
    // Last item index would be:
    var lastVisibleIndex = counterUp+maxItems;
    
    // If that item is possible, add it to the bottom of the list.
    if(lastVisibleIndex<=nameList_last){
      $('<div id="item'+lastVisibleIndex+'">'+nameList[lastVisibleIndex]+'</div>').insertAfter($("[id^='item']").last());;
    }

    // Decrease counterUp.
    counterUp++;
  }
  
  // Highlight the first item of the list.
  $("[id^='item']").css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
  $("[id^='item']").first().css({"background-color":"#FF4"});
}

$(window).on("load",function () { 
  for (i=0;i<nameList.length;i++){
    container.append('<div id="item'+i+'">'+nameList[i]+'</div>');
    if(i>=maxItems-1){
      break;
    }
  }
  $("[id^='item']").first().css({"background-color":"#FF4"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type=button onclick="Navi('Up');">Up </button><br>
<button type=button onclick="Navi('Down');">Down </button><br>

<div id="MyDivList" class="style_MyDivList">
  <div id="Total">10</div>
</div>
```

Feel free to ask for clarifications. ;)

---

**--EDIT--**

Okay, to have some kind of a cursor moving up and down in the 5 visible possibilities and have the items cycling in loop when the cursor is at top or bottom of the visible items is a bit more complicated...

I dropped the `counterUp` variable. Now, that is the visible indexes that matters. So I used [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store and easily get them. I also used a class to *highlight* the selected item. That is easy to target too.

The rest of the logic is quite the same...

```js
var nameList =  ["test1", "test2", "test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"];

var container = $("#MyDivList");
var maxItems = 5;
var nameList_length = nameList.length;
var nameList_last = nameList.length-1;



function Navi(a){

  // Get the index of the currently hihlighted item.
  var current = $(".highlighted").index()-1;  // That is the index in the actually existing elements... Minus 1 because of #Total

  // Remove hightlighting.
  $(".item").removeClass("highlighted");

  // Visible indexes
  var first = parseInt($(".item").first().data("index"));
  var last = parseInt($(".item").last().data("index"));
  var toAdd;

  if (a =="Up"){

    // If the first item is highlighted.
    if(current==0){

      // Remove the item at the bottom of the list.
      $(".item").last().remove();

      // If the first item is the first of the array.
      if(first==0){
        toAdd = nameList_last;
      }else{
        toAdd = first-1;
      }
      // Add it to the top of the list.
      $('<div class="item" data-index="'+toAdd+'">'+nameList[toAdd]+'</div>').insertBefore($(".item").first());

      // Highlight the first item of the list.
      $(".item").first().addClass("highlighted");

    }else{
      // Just highlight the previous item of the list.
      $(".item").eq(current-1).addClass("highlighted");
    }

    // If a == Down
  }else{

    // If the last item is highlighted.
    if(current>=maxItems-1){

      // If the last item is the last of the array.
      if(last==nameList_last){
        toAdd = 0;
      }else{
        toAdd = last+1;
      }

      // Remove the item on top of the list.
      $(".item").first().remove();

      // Add it to the bottom of the list.
      $('<div class="item" data-index="'+toAdd+'">'+nameList[toAdd]+'</div>').insertAfter($(".item").last());

      // Highlight the last item of the list.
      $(".item").last().addClass("highlighted");

    }else{
      // Just highlight the next item of the list.
      $(".item").eq(current+1).addClass("highlighted");
    }
  }
}

$(window).on("load",function () { 
  for (i=0;i<nameList.length;i++){
    container.append('<div class="item" data-index="'+i+'">'+nameList[i]+'</div>');
    if(i>=maxItems-1){
      break;
    }
  }
  $(".item").first().addClass("highlighted");
});
```

```css
.highlighted{
  background-color:#FF4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type=button onclick="Navi('Up');">Up </button><br>
<button type=button onclick="Navi('Down');">Down </button><br>

<div id="MyDivList" class="style_MyDivList">
  <div id="Total">10</div>
</div>
```

---

**--LAST EDIT--**

To "reset" the selections when the highlighting is on the last item and the user click on "Down"... or to set the selection to the bottom list when the highlight is on the first item and the user clicks on "Up"...

That is just two new conditions to add. You need to slightly modify the initial load function to make it load the top items or the bottom items.

See below.

```js
var nameList =  ["test1", "test2", "test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"];

var container = $("#MyDivList");
var maxItems = 5;
var nameList_length = nameList.length;
var nameList_last = nameList.length-1;



function Navi(a){

  // Get the index of the currently hihlighted item.
  var current = $(".highlighted").index()-1;  // That is the index in the actually existing elements... Minus 1 because of #Total

  // Remove hightlighting.
  $(".item").removeClass("highlighted");

  // Visible indexes
  var first = parseInt($(".item").first().data("index"));
  var last = parseInt($(".item").last().data("index"));
  var toAdd;

  if (a =="Up"){

    // If the first item is highlighted.
    if(current==0){
      
      // Load the bottom items.
      if(first==0){
        $(".item").remove();
        loadItems("bottom");
        return;
      }

      // Remove the item at the bottom of the list.
      $(".item").last().remove();

      // If the first item is the first of the array.
      if(first==0){
        toAdd = nameList_last;
      }else{
        toAdd = first-1;
      }
      // Add it to the top of the list.
      $('<div class="item" data-index="'+toAdd+'">'+nameList[toAdd]+'</div>').insertBefore($(".item").first());

      // Highlight the first item of the list.
      $(".item").first().addClass("highlighted");

    }else{
      // Just highlight the previous item of the list.
      $(".item").eq(current-1).addClass("highlighted");
    }

    // If a == Down
  }else{

    // If the last item is highlighted.
    if(current>=maxItems-1){

      // Load the top items.
      if(last==nameList_last){
        $(".item").remove();
        loadItems("top");
        return;
      }
      
      // If the last item is the last of the array.
      if(last==nameList_last){
        toAdd = 0;
      }else{
        toAdd = last+1;
      }

      // Remove the item on top of the list.
      $(".item").first().remove();

      // Add it to the bottom of the list.
      $('<div class="item" data-index="'+toAdd+'">'+nameList[toAdd]+'</div>').insertAfter($(".item").last());

      // Highlight the last item of the list.
      $(".item").last().addClass("highlighted");

    }else{
      // Just highlight the next item of the list.
      $(".item").eq(current+1).addClass("highlighted");
    }
  }
}

function loadItems(part){
  if(part=="top"){
    for (i=0;i<nameList_length;i++){
      container.append('<div class="item" data-index="'+i+'">'+nameList[i]+'</div>');
      if(i>=maxItems-1){
        break;
      }
    }
    $(".item").first().addClass("highlighted");
  }
  
  if(part=="bottom"){
    for (i=(nameList_length-maxItems);i<nameList_length;i++){
      container.append('<div class="item" data-index="'+i+'">'+nameList[i]+'</div>');
    }
    $(".item").last().addClass("highlighted");
  }
}

$(window).on("load",function () { 
  loadItems("top");
});
```

```css
.highlighted{
  background-color:#FF4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type=button onclick="Navi('Up');">Up </button><br>
<button type=button onclick="Navi('Down');">Down </button><br>

<div id="MyDivList" class="style_MyDivList">
  <div id="Total">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for cool demo . Is it possible to start removing items after first 5 items ?In your current demo the yellow bar doesn't move downward but i want the yellow bar moves until 5 item and after that it stays static as your demo and start removing one item from start of list!(Furthermore,when end of list reached i want the list box start showing from its from begging instead of stopping)

Comment: Many thanks almost the way i wanted ! After reaching end of list is it possible to re create the list by moving higlight back to beginng of list pointing at test1?(Furthermore if i am at start of list and i press Up how to move highlitght to test10 at bottom of list while showing last 5 items?)

Comment: I've done it... It was a simple addition of two conditions. Now you should play with that script by yourself and create a new question if you face new issues. I've done more than just a quick help here, I coded it all for you. But I have to admit it was fun.